# What to specify for Local ManagementScope

Tags: c#, wmi, hyper-v

I am trying to connect (locally) to get a list of virtual machines and their properties.  I have hacked some code I found, but my code is failing to connect so I can only assume that the connection string is wrong.

Using Server 2012, Hyper-V

```
private void listVirtualMachines() {

    ManagementScope manScope = new ManagementScope(@"\\LOCALHOST\root\cimv2");

        if (manScope.IsConnected) {

            ObjectQuery queryObj = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Msvm_ComputerSystem");

            // connect and set up our search
            ManagementObjectSearcher vmSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(manScope, queryObj);

            ManagementObjectCollection vmCollection = vmSearcher.Get();

            // loop through the machines
            foreach (ManagementObject vm in vmCollection) {
                // display VM details
                LogString(vm["ElementName"].ToString());
                LogString(vm["EnabledState"].ToString());
                LogString(vm["Description"].ToString());
            }
        } else {
            //WE END UP HERE EVERY TIME!
            LogString("Cannot Connect to ManagementScope!");
        }

    } //funct
```

Comment: `manScope.Connect();` is missing.

Comment: Oops. Thanks for that. I still think the ManagementScope is wrong though.  I get an exception at the for each statement "...Invalid class"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Server 2012, [Msvm_ComputerSystem](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850116%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is in the WMI namespace `root\virtualization\v2` so the code should be:

```
ManagementScope manScope = new ManagementScope(@"\\.\root\virtualization\v2");
manScope.Connect();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I must be doing something else wrong: I am still getting "An unhandled exception...'System.Management.ManagementException' occurred in Sysetm.Management.dll / Additional Info: Invalid Class

Comment: @EnigmaPlus the namespace version changed for Server 2012, edited answer

Comment: Brilliant. I'd love to know how you found that out?  I'm finding Microsoft documentation to be an absolute nightmare.